# I can't believe I'm working with frames (facebook)

Tags: html, facebook, iframe, frame, href

I haven't dealt with this since the mid 90's.

```
 <a href="http://www.google.com" class="learnmorebutton">learn more</a>
```

When I click a link to say http://www.google.com, facebook renders google in the frame. I don't want this. I want the link to take me to google and out of facebook.com.

See the image to see the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
<a target="_top" href="...">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must put an attribute to the tag a: target="_top" or if you want to open in new window: target="_blank"